# One sample student t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

[image]

My teacher solved it this way
H0: μ=140
HA: μ different from 140.Significance level 0.05. Test in two sides. alpha/2=0.05/2=0.025. For this alpha and df=8, we get t(tab)=+-2.896. t cal (using the formula) is 5.

For df=9-1=8 and t=5 alpha=0.001. The difference between mean concentrations is due to chance.

But I disagree. As the t cal> t tab and alpha is 0.001<0.05, the difference is significant. Am I right?

Comment: It's not alpha but the p-value, which is $0.001$, and you are right, the difference is significant. The 95% confidence interval for the sodium concentration of the $9$ students is $[145.4,     154.6]$.